# Calculate a triple integral where the integrand has some symmetry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate
$$I = \iiint\limits_{V_n}x^{n-1}y^{n-1}z^{n-1}\sqrt{1-x^n-y^n-z^n}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where
$$V_n = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^n + y^n + z^n \leq 1,\ x \geq
0,\  y \geq 0,\ z \geq 0\},\ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+,\ n \geq 1$$

I tried changing variables, and applying symmetry arguments. I think I
can use mathematical induction, but I have to guess what is the final
result. Any hints in these directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested,
$$ I(n) = \frac{1}{n^3}\iiint_{0\leq x+y+z \leq 1}\sqrt{1-(x+y+z)}\,dx\,dy\,dz =\frac{C}{n^3}$$
where the value of $C$ is given by

$$\begin{eqnarray*} C &=& \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-x-y}\sqrt{1-x-y-z}\,dz\,dy\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}s^2\sqrt{1-s}\,ds\\&\stackrel{s\mapsto 1-u^2}{=}&\int_{0}^{1}u^2(1-u^2)^2\,dt = \frac{8}{105}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\,s^2\sqrt{1-s}\,ds$?

Comment: Just by making a change of variables where x+y+z=s

Comment: Thanks, I know, but how did you get $s^2$. I don't see how to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Try $(u,v,w)=(x^n,y^n,z^n)$ to start with.